# ASP .NET 2.0 integration with ASP .NET MVC 2.0 

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

Is there any reason why this configuration should not work?:

- parent application (A) is a closed (uneditable) ASP .NET 2.0 application in IIS 6.0
- an ASP .NET MVC 2.0 (B) application installed in a subfolder of A; however the MVC application CANNOT be set as an application in IIS as A will then not pass security information through

I have worked out that authentication nodes in B’s web.config have to be stripped out. Also, I know of the application mappings that are required to get MVC routing working in IIS 6.

What else needs to be done to fire up the MVC part from A without recompiling A? Are there any differences if the web server was IIS 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that the child application (B) is inheriting the web.config settings from the parent application (A).

You can turn off inheritance by adding a location tag around the system.web tag in the web.config of the parent.

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.web>
  ...
  </system.web>   
</location>
```

for more details:
http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx